# I'm trying to check if the user exist with asynchronus function in (Firebase + Vue) but when I test with slow connection, return that user not exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

When is a slow connection, the code returns 0, I think that doesn't wait for async function will be executed to continue. I let you the code, Thanks!

```
login(){
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(() => {
       this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
     
       if (this.user.emailVerified){
          console.log("user verified!");
          const res = this.checkUser();
          res.
          then( data => {
            console.log(data.docs.length);
             })

        } else {
              this.$router.replace({name: "mail-verification"});
        }
})

 async checkUser() {
   try {
        const response = await db.collection("users")
        .where("user_id", "==", this.user.email ).get();
        return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data from Firebase:', error);
   }
},
```

I'm trying with async function.
I hope that the function login() waits for the function checkUser() will check it if the user is already created or not to continue.